# Gradle -  load jar from maven and use as part of build

Tags: maven, gradle

From my gradle build I want to minify my html as part of the build process using html compressor, which exists as a maven artifact: http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/#Maven_Artifact

The jar should be loaded from maven central and new versions should be automatically used as they are released.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, no Gradle plugin exists to simplify this task that I am aware of. I think it would be great if you would write one and contribute it to the community. For now you could probably use the [Ant tasks](http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/#Setting_up_Ant_task_to_compress_files) provided by htmlcompressor. Make sure the input and output directories actually exist before running the task. The version qualifier in the dependency definition lets you pull newer versions by using a plus sign e.g. `1.+`. I would not recommend doing that as it might break your build if the Ant task definition changes with a newer version.

```
configurations {
    htmlcompressor
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    htmlcompressor 'com.googlecode.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor:1.4'
}

task compressHtml << {
    ant.apply(executable: "java", parallel: false) {
        fileset(dir: "test", includes: "*.html") {
            exclude(name: "**/leave/**")
        }

        arg(value: "-jar")
        arg(path: configurations.htmlcompressor.asPath)
        arg(line: "--type html")
        arg(value: "--preserve-comments")
        srcfile()
        arg(value: "-o")
        mapper(type: "glob", from: "*", to: "compressed/*")
        targetfile()
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** You don't actually need to add the dependency to the script's classpath. Using a configuration for it is much cleaner. I changed the script to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using a similar method but executed it using an Exec task. I'm bit of a gradle newbie, but once I have more experience I will look at writing a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

> The jar should be loaded from maven central and new versions should be automatically used as they are released.

Can be done with the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
    htmlcompressor 'com.googlecode.htmlcompressor:htmlcompressor:latest.integration'
}
```